# Configuring mod_jk to communicate Tomcat 8 and Apache 2.4 on CentOS7

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, centos7

I've installed Apache 2.4 and Tomcat 8 on a CentOS 7 VM and both work fine.

Now I'd like to install and configure mod_jk, an apache httpd module used to make apache tomcat applications interact with a httpd server.

I've tried to follow this step-by-step tutorial http://www.diegoacuna.me/installing-mod_jk-on-apache-httpd-in-centos-6-x7-x/ downloading the last mod_jk version source code and compiling it on my CentOS7 system.

I've configured my Tomcat installation `service.xml` file then I've created a 
`/etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_jk.conf` its contents is

```
LoadModule jk_module "/etc/httpd/modules/mod_jk.so"

JkWorkersFile /etc/httpd/conf/workers.properties
# Where to put jk shared memory
JkShmFile     /var/run/httpd/mod_jk.shm
# Where to put jk logs
JkLogFile     /var/log/httpd/mod_jk.log
# Set the jk log level [debug/error/info]
JkLogLevel    info
# Select the timestamp log format
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
#JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"
#JkEnvVar SSL_CLIENT_V_START worker1
```

and then a file `/etc/httpd/conf/workers.properties` its contents is

```
workers.apache_log=/var/log/httpd
worker.list=app1Worker
worker.stat1.type=status

worker.app1Worker.type=ajp13
worker.app1Worker.host=192.168.33.10 #put your app host here
worker.app1Worker.port=8009
```

and, latest, a file `/etc/httpd/conf.d/192.168.33.10.conf` its contents is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 192.168.33.10
    ServerAdmin admin@myhost.com
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" combined
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/192.168.33.10_access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/192.168.33.10_error.log
    <IfModule mod_jk.c>
       JkMount /* app1Worker
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I've stop and start both Apache and Tomcat and the situation is:

```
http://192.168.33.10: ok Apache is working
http://192.168.33.10:8080: ok, Tomcat is working 
http://192.168.33.10:8080/examples: ok, Tomcat is working
http://192.168.33.10/examples: KO .... ?????
```

Probably there are some errors in my configurations but I don't know where: any suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Looking at an ubuntu installation with mod_jk from the repository (I never bother to compile from source), I find the following lines, related to yours but not identical:

```
LoadModule jk_module "/etc/httpd/modules/mod_jk.so"
```

and, the important one:

```
<IfModule jk_module>
```

And the description of your problem sounds like your `<IfModule mod_jk.c>` block is not taken into account